# Jquery How to get Assign in for Loop

Tags: jquery

I'm working with TPL-Files. I assigned variables in PHP to my TPL FILE.

For Example:

```
ArtikelID1 = 10
ArtikelID2 = 20
ArtikelID3 = 30
```

Now I have a Jquery Loop and want to get them.

My Problem is i cant get the assigned variable.

`{$ArtikelNr1}` works but what i want to do is

```
for($a = 1; $a <= $artikelAnzahl; $a++){
      /* $artikelID = '{$ArtikelNr1}'; */
      $artikelNr = '{$ArtikelNr + $a}';

}
```

But this don't work..

Please Help.

Thanks

Edit:

```
if($a == 1){
     $artikelNr = '{$ArtikelNr1}';
     $artikelSource = '{$ArtikelSource1}';
}
else if($a == 2){
     $artikelNr = '{$ArtikelNr2}';
     $artikelSource = '{$ArtikelSource2}';
}
else if($a == 3){
     $artikelNr = '{$ArtikelNr3}';
     $artikelSource = '{$ArtikelSource3}';
}



insertArticle($artikelSource, $artikelNr);
```

- This is working but i dont want to make a if for all assigned
  Article Ids i want to get it dynamicly with $a

Comment: Nobody here who can help?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating PHP variable, you have to concatenate using PHP and not JS, your code would be:

```
$artikelNr = '{$ArtikelNr'.$a.'}';
```

Comment: yes i know but i have to get the article ID in jquery not in PHP

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you need in the end.

Comment: I want to get all assigned article Ids in Jquery to work with them